# Rendering static Rails page with Nginx takes too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have deployed a Rails 6 application with Nginx as a reverse proxy.
The application is a dummy just to check everything works as expected.

The only available page is correctly rendered but it takes more than a minute for rendering the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>R6</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="cW6aQ_Oqw8cfV1xDQZRQ-ypwySqernI_b5uMG41i1use-Yj8IhWPAaftnsDGqaeNkIl2xnrukkiHyJIh4Hdxnw" />
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/packs/js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>DUMMY APP Https</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Here the Nginx log

```
$ tail -f /usr/nginx/log/access.log
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 103 1910 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /packs/js/application-76cbbc8f0300eca44b41.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
213.200.220.226 - - [21/Feb/2022:08:47:51 +0000] "GET /assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "https://staging.example.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0" "-"
```

Here the Nginx config

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=app_cache:5m max_size=250m inactive=60m;

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name staging.example.ch;

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /data/letsencrypt;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name staging.example.ch;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location ~ \.(php|asp|exe|pl|cgi|scgi) {
    deny all;
  }

  # your static assets you want to cache
  location /assets {
    proxy_cache                 app_cache;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache    $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_ignore_headers        Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid any       10m;
    proxy_cache_use_stale       error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass                  http://app:3000;        # container you want to forward to
  }

  location / {
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;

    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self'; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rollbar.js; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://cloudflare.com; font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://cloudflare.com; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests;" always;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://app:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
  }
```

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your packs precompiled?

Comment: Yes. They have been pre compiled while building the Docker image.

Comment: Can you add your Nginx logs?

Comment: Log added. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be moved permanently (301) to "https://staging.example.ch". Is it possible to add you Nginx configuration?
Pay attention to allowed hosts on Rails 6. If `staging.example.ch` is not added to your Rails app, request cannot access your app.

Comment: Nginx config added. Does "allowed hosts" apply also to production?

Comment: Of course they do! And it's a great feature to avoid basic security issue.  I don't see `staging.inforlife.ch` on your nginx config. If this is your current config pay attention to `staging.example.ch`. You need to own those domain (unless none url will be able to lead to it) + this domain needs to be added on the `config/environments/production.rb` with something like `config.hosts = ['.the-example.ch']`

Comment: According to several sources (here 1: https://prathamesh.tech/2019/09/02/dns-rebinding-attacks-protection-in-rails-6/#guard-against-dns-rebinding-attack-in-rails-6) the guard is active by default for the `development` environment and can be availed optionally for other environments. As a confirmation, I have other 3 Rails 6 apps in production and none of them have `config.hosts` defined. I'm not saying it's best practice not to define it but from my experience that can't be the cause of the issue I'm facing. As a final proof, I have added `config.hosts << '.example.ch'` and the issue remains.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for sharing.  
It seems that your assets request is redirected to root `/`. There isn't any `200` response here. I would say problem comes from `/assets` definition on your nginx config.